# JavaScript Access variable value without simplifying

Tags: javascript

Say I make a variable like this:

```
var a = 1+1;
```

and if I do this:

```
alert(a);
```

I will get 2.
But I want the alert box to say 1+1, not 2. Is there a way to do this?
I have tried many things without any success.

Comment: Just print as a string;`var a='1+1'`

Comment: `a="1+1"` will do it, since that is a string.

Comment: have you tried `a = '1+1';`?

Comment: You could technically use `var a = {toString(){ return "1+1"; }, valueOf(){ return 2; }}`. Whenever you use `a` as a string, it will show as `1+1`, whenever you use it as a number, it will be used as `2`.

Answer (score 3):

**No**.

Because, you are assigning the result of the math operation to the variable `a`, and not the text of that operation.

The only way to show it is if you made the math equation a String.

```
alert("1+1")
```

or

```
var a = "1+1";
alert(a);
```

Then, if you needed to actually compute the `1+1` you could eval it like so:

```
var a = "1+1"; // string
var b = eval(a); // number
alert(a); // 1+1
alert(b); // 2
```